# Creating Hive external table on AWS EMR

Tags: amazon-s3, hive, amazon-emr

I am trying to create an external table in `hive` via `hue` on `AWS EMR`

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS urls (
  id STRING,
  `date` TIMESTAMP,
  url STRING,
  expandedUrl STRING,
  domain STRING
) 
PARTITIONED BY (`year` INT, `month` INT, `day` INT)
STORED AS PARQUET LOCATION 's3://data/processed/urls/'
```

- I have created and `EMR` cluster (emr-5.4.0) using the AWS console.
- Logged into `Hue`
- Run the above `SQL`

In the Metastore Manager I get the following error:

> Cannot access: s3://data/processed/urls/. Note:
>   you are a Hue admin but not a HDFS superuser, "hdfs" or part of HDFS
>   supergroup, "hadoop".
>
> [Errno 22] Unknown scheme s3, available schemes: ['hdfs']

I also can't see s3 under the File Manager.
I can access s3 from the master node using the CLI tools.

Are there any config options I am missing from the cluster creation?
Do I need to give the Hue user additional permissions?

**UPDATE**

I have tried creating an hdfs user and a new database, as franklinsijo suggested.

I now get the same error on the database:

> Cannot access: s3://data/processed.
>
> [Errno 22] Unknown scheme s3, available schemes: ['hdfs']

When the "create database" SQL is run from the hive CLI I get "Access Denied" 
I am using `EMR_DefaultRole` which has both `AmazonElasticMapReduceRole` and `AmazonS3FullAccess`

**UPDATE 2**

I have worked through the issue with help from franklinsijo

- I can create databases and tables on s3 from both the `hive cli` and the `hue`.
- I can read and write data from the tables
- I **can't** see `S3 Browser` as detailed in http://gethue.com/introducing-s3-support-in-hue/
- I **can't** access the table via 'Metastore Manager -> Database -> Table -> STATS -> Location'. I still get [Errno 22]

Answer (score 2):

> [Errno 22] Unknown scheme s3, available schemes: ['hdfs']

This is because Hive's `default` database location is set as HDFS (Refer [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-hue-s3-metastore.html)). Create a new Hive database with S3 location.

```
CREATE DATABASE database_name LOCATION 'S3://Bucket/Key';
```

Then create tables in this newly created database.

> Cannot access: s3://data/processed/urls/. Note: you are a Hue admin
>   but not a HDFS superuser, "hdfs" or part of HDFS supergroup, "hadoop".

Create a new Hue user named `hdfs` with Superuser status in Hue UI. Login as `hdfs` user to execute queries.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have created the "hdfs" user and logged in as it. I also created the database as suggested. However the issue is the same, It is as if hive/hue don't support s3

Comment: The error is now on the database (not the table):

Cannot access: s3://data/processed.

[Errno 22] Unknown scheme s3, available schemes: ['hdfs']

Comment: You are using the `hue` that came along with emr isn't it?

Comment: yes. I am using default install.
Hive 2.1.1, Pig 0.16.0, Hue 3.11.0

Comment: Strange! Can you try to the `create database` query in hive CLI

Comment: Getting closer. I am logged in as the "hadoop" user and now get. Access Denied...

java.io.IOException com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied

Comment: The IAM role associated with the EMR, does it have access to S3?

Comment: Just checked the permissions. I am using "EMR_DefaultRole" which has both "AmazonElasticMapReduceRole" and "AmazonS3FullAccess"